# Converse of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem states that every bounded sequence has a limit point. But, the converse is not true.

That is, there are some unbounded sequences which have a limit point. In my course book, I found an example for this claim, but it doesn't make sense.

Here's the example give in the book:
The set: {1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, ...} is unbounded, but has a limit point of `1`. 
I can't understand how this set has a limit point as `1`.  According to the book definition of limit point, 'x' is the limit point of a sequence, if every neighborhood of 'x' has infinitely many elements of the sequence. If I apply it here, then I get only infinity as the limit point. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As others have pointed out already, the book's example works fine. Having said that, here is an example you might like more: $1, \frac{1}{2}, 3, \frac{1}{4}, 5, \frac{1}{6}, \ldots$ . Clearly it is an unbounded sequence which has a (possibly more satisfying) limit point at $0$.

Comment: I know this isn't answering your question (there are other posts below for that), but as some additional information, note that if a sequence is convergent (not just "has a limit point", ie "has a subsequence that converges"), then it is in fact bounded -- the proof is a little exercise :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems there is some confusion between sets and sequences.  In this example, what you have written as "{1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, ...}" is not meant to be a *set* but rather a *sequence* $(a_n)$ with $a_0=1,a_1=2,a_2=1,a_3=4,\dots$.

In particular, then, when we say a point $x$ is a limit point of $(a_n)$, this means that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exist infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\in U$.  It does *not* mean there are infinitely many *different* numbers in the sequence which are in $U$, since these values of $a_n$ for different $n$ might actually be the same.  So in this case, since every neighborhood of $1$ contains $1$, it contains $a_0,a_2,a_4,\dots$, and so $1$ is a limit point of the sequence.

(In contrast, $1$ is *not* a limit point of the *set* $\{1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, \dots\}=\{1, 2, 4, 6, \dots\}$ because $(0,2)$ is a neighborhood of $1$ that contains only one element of this set, namely $1$.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion! It was indeed between sets and sequences.

Comment: Eric, very clear and nice as usual

Comment: @Sankalp: That's why I think we should never use curly-braces "{ }" for sequences...

Answer (score 7):

We have

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 1, & n \text{ is odd} \\ n, & n \text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

$1$ appears infinitely often. Hence there is a subsequence that always take value $1$. That subsequence converges to $1$. Hence $1$ is a limit to the subsequence.

Comment: But, according to the limit point definition, 'x' is the limit point of a sequence, if every neighborhood of 'x' has infinitely many elements of the sequence.

Comment: I think Bolzano states that every bounded sequence has a convergence subsequence.

Comment: The third paragraph of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) might be of interest to you

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, there are two types of confusions. First, a set is being mixed with a sequence. Secondly, limit point of a sequence is being confused with the limit of a sequence. If we take care of these two ( limit of a sequence and limit point of a sequence), then the things are very much clear.
Obviously, in this problem, if we regard this as a sequence
1,2,1,4,1,6,... this sequence is clearly unbounded. But, it has a subsequence {a_n}, where  a_n=1  for every natural number n.     This subsequence has limit 1, because it converges to 1.
If we regard {a_n} as a set , then {a_n }={ 1}, for all n. This set has no limit point. Because,  we take a neighborhood (1/2, 2) of 1, this neighborhood doesn't contain any other point (different from 1) of the set {1}, so 1 is not a limit point of the set {1}. By the same argument, it shows that 1 is not limit point of the set { 1,2,4,6,...}...
Also, 1 is not the limit of the sequence
1,2,1,4,1,6,1,...

The things will be cleared if we focus on the definitions of  limit point of a set and limit point of a sequence.

Usually, we talk about the limit of a sequence not about limit point of a sequence. This is the basic fact that creates confusion.

NOTE:
Importantly, whenever we talk about limit point of a sequence, it is meant limit point of range set of that sequence.